# occasional EEPROM corruption in phyCARD

Tags: flash, linux, error

I am trying to find a root cause for corrupted EEPROM in phyCARD PCB.
PhyCard is so called "System on Module". You can find some more info here:
https://www.phytec.eu/product-eu/system-on-modules/phycard-imx-6-download/
I use this board together with an adapter PCB, which contains voltage supply and
some connectors to camera and other stuff.

We have few boards in the company and they are working really fine.
Mistakes happen during routine service control once per year.
Boards are connected to a test device, which checks voltage level, power consumption,
CAN connection, FW Version etc.

Errors occurred by roughly 5% of tests and is hard to reproduce.
My service software cannot establish CAN connection and read out FW Version.

Here are the things that I have already checked:

1. I connected the PhyCard to evaluation board developed by its manufacturer and
   noticed that only bootloader is still there. Barebox and Kernel is not responding.
   The only way to revive the board is to flash it one more time with Barebox and Kernel.
2. I checked voltage level during my routine service control process.
   It was pretty stable 3,3V.

What can be a root cause of this? What can damage my EEPROM? Is it happening due to
voltage malfunction or brownout?

I know that it's hard to say something without getting detailed
description but maybe you have already encountered similar problem.

Comment: What makes you think that the EEPROM is **damaged**? I would think that the problem is more likely software error or power loss during the write cycle.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean that it burns or permanently damages EEPROM. What I wanted to say was that some external factor damages my application flashed in EEPROM.  It should be read only memory but somehow is getting corrupt.

Comment: Your statement ". It was pretty stable 3,3V." has me concerned. What protection is incorporated to support EEPROM write in case of power brownout or failure. Posting a schematic of the system may help us narrow down your problem. I believe it is external factors causing the problem. Also no idea what the environment is where these are used and tested.